# How to apply temporary pins to PCB

Tags: pcb, soldering

I want to temporarily solder a pin on my pcb where I know for a fact that it's going to be moved soon. Is there a better way? Is there like a plastic piece I can attach to the other side of the exposed wire that will allow me to temporarily attach this wire there?

I realize that's where a bread board is used but unfortunately I'm doing testing on an existing PCB and I don't want to keep applying solder only to have to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also would usually solder a test pin or wire on there, but if I happen to be using a part with legs instead of a qfn or bga, I sometimes reach for the micro grabbers.   These are small enough to claw onto single pins without shorting the adjacent ones

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with soldering a temporary pin, wire, test point and desoldering it after you are done.  I do this sort of thing often.  <sup>1</sup>

In your future PCB designs, you can lay out designated landings for test points and use them for temporary attachment.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I'm assuming that you PCB is one-off, as oppsed to production.</sub>